# Storing the text of a cell in a string variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the creation of PowerPoint slides using VBA. I'm new and I'm learning by myself so I'm going step by step. Currently I'm trying to automate just one slide. I've made the code to create the charts I need for that slide and the code to put it in the right place in the PowerPoint (for sure I'll need to change some stuff) and i created another Sub to create all the charts and PowerPoints at the same time.
There are +/- 40 stores and each PPT contains a slide with the graph for that store and the zone in which the store is cointained.

[Above there are the stores and then the zones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEXLR.png)

I'm trying to store in a variable called "nome" the value of the name of each store inside a for but i get an error saying the method range of object _global failed here "nome = range(Cells(4, i)).Text". I've looked everywhere and i can't figure out how to do it right. Here's the code:

```
Sub TesteTUDO()


    Dim nome As String
    Dim zona As String
    Dim ra As range
    Dim rb As range



        For i = 3 To 47
        nome = range(Cells(4, i)).Text
            Set ra = range(Cells(5, i), Cells(7, i))
            Call TesteCriarGrafico(ra)

            Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\HP EliteBook 840\Desktop\Lojas por Zona de Vida.xlsm")



        For j = 1 To 47
        If StrComp(Cells(j, A), nome, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If range(Cells(j, A)).Text = nome Then
                zona = Application.ActiveSheet.range(Cells(j, B)).Text
                Workbooks("Lojas por Zona de Vida.xlsm").Close

                Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\HP EliteBook 840\Desktop\Ficheiro Resultado.xlsm")
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


        For y = 3 To 9
            If range(Cells(13, y)).Text = zona Then
                Set rb = range(Cells(14, y), Cells(16, y))
                Call TesteCriarGrafico(rb)
                Call TesteCriarPPT (nome)
                Else
                End If
            Next y
        Else
        End If
        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: `nome = Cells(4, i).Value`

Comment: A look at the documentation would have helped. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text and then the other properties for the Range object. It's all there for you to read.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks!